# Make the string lexicographically smallest and non palindromic by replacing exactly one character

Tags: python, algorithm, time-complexity, palindrome, greedy

Given a palindromic string palindrome, replace exactly one character by any lowercase English letter so that the string becomes the lexicographically smallest possible string that isn't a palindrome.

After doing so, return the final string.  If there is no way to do so, return the empty string.

I have come up with the following, which takes O(n) time and O(1) space:

```
def breakPalindrome(self, S):
    for i in xrange(len(S) / 2):
        if S[i] != 'a':
            return S[:i] + 'a' + S[i + 1:]
    return S[:-1] + 'b' if S[:-1] else ''
```

Is there a better solution?
Please correct me if there's some mistake in time or space complexity.

Comment: Your time is definitely O(n).  You are building a new string, so I could argue that space is also O(n).

Comment: Forget the iteration; if you're modifying a string at some index, a minimum of O(N) time will be guaranteed

Answer (score 0):

- Bug in your code: Odd palindromes. Input 'aba' gives output 'abb'. The correct output should be 'aaa'
- Return "" on `len(palindrome) == 1` is not a right thing to do. I would treat empty string as a palindrome.
- Strings are immutable in python. So, space complexity of your solution is `O(n)`. It can't be any better.
- There can't be a better solution in terms of space or time complexity. You have to check the whole string in the worst case e.g. string contains only 'a's.
- In languages where strings are mutable e.g. C++, the space complexity could be `O(1)` as one can change a character at an index in constant time like `palindrome[i] = 'a'` or `palindrome[palindrome.size() - 1] = 'b'`.

Comment: aaa is a palindrome.